# tkinter readonly combobox with autocomplete

Tags: python, combobox, autocomplete, tkinter

I am trying to make a combobox in tkinter with python 3 that has autocomplete when the first letter is pressed, but is also readonly, so that only names in the list are selectable.

There's some old code which works well for autocomplete:

```
class AutocompleteCombobox(ttk.Combobox):  #https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tkinter-discuss/2012-January/003041.html

        def set_completion_list(self, completion_list):
                """Use our completion list as our drop down selection menu, arrows move through menu."""
                self._completion_list = completion_list  #sorted(completion_list, key=str.lower) # Work with a sorted list
                self._hits = []
                self._hit_index = 0
                self.position = 0
                self.bind('<KeyRelease>', self.handle_keyrelease)
                self['values'] = self._completion_list  # Setup our popup menu

        def autocomplete(self, delta=0):
                """autocomplete the Combobox, delta may be 0/1/-1 to cycle through possible hits"""
                if delta: # need to delete selection otherwise we would fix the current position
                        self.delete(self.position, END)
                else: # set position to end so selection starts where textentry ended
                        self.position = len(self.get())
                # collect hits
                _hits = []
                for element in self._completion_list:
                        if element.lower().startswith(self.get().lower()): # Match case insensitively
                                _hits.append(element)
                # if we have a new hit list, keep this in mind
                if _hits != self._hits:
                        self._hit_index = 0
                        self._hits=_hits
                # only allow cycling if we are in a known hit list
                if _hits == self._hits and self._hits:
                        self._hit_index = (self._hit_index + delta) % len(self._hits)
                # now finally perform the auto completion
                if self._hits:
                        self.delete(0,END)
                        self.insert(0,self._hits[self._hit_index])
                        self.select_range(self.position,END)

        def handle_keyrelease(self, event):
                """event handler for the keyrelease event on this widget"""
                if event.keysym == "BackSpace":
                        self.delete(self.index(INSERT), END)
                        self.position = self.index(END)
                if event.keysym == "Left":
                        if self.position < self.index(END): # delete the selection
                                self.delete(self.position, END)
                        else:
                                self.position = self.position-1 # delete one character
                                self.delete(self.position, END)
                if event.keysym == "Right":
                        self.position = self.index(END) # go to end (no selection)
                if len(event.keysym) == 1:
                        self.autocomplete()
                # No need for up/down, we'll jump to the popup
                # list at the position of the autocompletion
```

But the challenge is that this does not work if you set the state to "readonly":

```
self.combo1 = AutocompleteCombobox(mainframe, width=12, state="readonly")
```

What I'd like is for the combobox to jump to the first name in the list that starts with a given letter if I press that letter, and remain blank if there isn't a valid name starting with that letter.

The other, related issue, is that the ComboboxSelected binding is not triggered when using the above autocomplete:

```
self.combo1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.selected)
```

will trigger self.selected when you select using the usual methods (clicking on the drop down list, or pressing the up/down arrows), but not when you get an autocomplete.

Comment: Have you tried reconfiguring it to writeable, making the change, then reconfiguring to read-only?

Comment: No.  I'm not sure how I would do that.  If you change it to readonly from writeable, and the current value is not on the list, then it will still keep the current value.  I guess that's not necessarily important, but if you typed a letter that was not a valid starting character, then it would probably just keep it there

Comment: Does it work properly when it hasn't been initialized as read-only? If so, then the idea is to go to the exact place that modifies the widget's contents, and before it does so, you tell it to make the widget writeable. After it's done writing in the value, have it immediately set it back to read-only. For your `AutocompleteCombobox`, put `self.config(state='normal')` before each `self.insert...` call, and `self.config(state='readonly')` after.

Comment: Correction: set the state to normal before any call that modifies the widget's contents, including `delete()` as well as `insert()`, then back to read-only afterward.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'll try it tomorrow and post back

Comment: In the end I decided to leave the state as normal, and pass the tk object into the AutocompleteCombobox object so that I could create a binding.  Slightly different solution, but seems to work fine.  I guess one could rewrite the AutocompleteCombobox to make it robust against typing, but in the end this works fine.